# How do I get the text of the next span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my HTML.  I'm at the `<select>` element, how do I get the text from the next span element on the page?  I've tried several things, including `$( this ).nextAll( 'span:first' ).text();` where `$( this )` is my select element, but I'm not getting the desire result.

```
<ul id="questions">
   <div>What do you want information about?</div>
   <li>
      <p>
         <select><!-- This is where I'm at. -->
            <option>Click to select...</option>
            <option data-next_select_name="foos">
               a foo
            </option>
            <option data-next_select_name="bars">
               a bar
            </option>
         </select>
      </p>
      <div>
         <a>
            <span>a foo</span><!-- I want the text out of this span. -->
            <div><b></b></div>
         </a>
         <div>
            <div><input type="text" /></div>
            <ul>
               <li>Click to select...</li>
               <li>
                  a foo
               </li>
               <li>
                  a bar
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <p></p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just incase your html structure changes and `.next()` isn't an option, I always prefer to go up to the definitive parent (in this case the list-item)

```
$(this).closest('li')
       .find('span').first().text();
```

Random side note: `.first()` is faster than `:first`

Answer (score 3):

`nextAll` selects  next siblings of an  element, the span element is not one of the siblings of your selects element:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('span:first').text()
```

Comment: Also `$(this).closest('li').find('span:first')`

Comment: Ugh, yeah, I could do that, but I was trying to avoid using `parent`.  Is there any way to just say "jQuery, get me the next of this type of element on the page"?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS ah yes... closest!  I knew there was a way.  I had done it before, but couldn't remember!  Thanks! Add an answer to get your points!

Comment: No typoknig, mcpDESIGNS has the best solution I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( this ).parent().next().find('span:first').text()
```